# Django: extended user with proxy model to add extra method, how to use the method in template?

Tags: django

I extend the default user model with a proxy model to add an extra method.

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Person(User):

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def custom_method(self):
        pass
```

The main purpose is to use the method in templates.

```
<div>{{ user.custom_method }}</div>
```

But since the `user` is pointing to the default user model, it has no access to  the `custom_method`.

Is there any way to achieve this other than create a subclass of the `User` model?

=== UPDATE ==============

I ended up with custom backends:
(not sure if this solution has any drawbacks)

```py
# user proxy

class ExtendedUser(get_user_model()):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True

    def custom_method(self):
        ...
```

```py
# backends

from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend
# since I'm using allauth
from allauth.account.auth_backends import AuthenticationBackend
from .models import ExtendedUser


class DjangoModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        print("\n\n\ncustom user!!!")
        try:
            user = ExtendedUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except ExtendedUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None


class AuthModelBackend(DjangoModelBackend, AuthenticationBackend):
    pass
```

And in `settings.py`, add these to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`.

Comment: Thanks but seems that's [not possible](https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/FcJm7f12UIY)

Comment: perhaps monkey patching the user is a better idea

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to *monkey patch* the user model. Indeed, in one of the [**`AppConfig`s** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig) we can implement this with:

```
# app_name/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def custom_method(self):
    return 'Some value'

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app_name'

    def ready(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        User.custom_method = custom_method
```

Here we thus add a method to the user model that can then be called in views, templates, etc.